# Are campaign contributions to NON government positions tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, charity

If someone is running for an elected position on a private university board, and you donate to them, is that a tax-deductible contribution? Or does the "no tax deductions for campaigns" refer to non government campaigns too.

Comment: Before it can be a 501(c)(3) organization, it has to be a 501(c) nonprofit.  Is the entity receiving the contributions a non-profit?  Do they have 501(c) status?

Comment: In this hypothetical I'm talking about a nonprofit and receiving contributions as a nonprofit. But I guess [this IRS publication](http://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/the-restriction-of-political-campaign-intervention-by-section-501c3-tax-exempt-organizations) says this only applies to 'public' elections.